# Get the 2nd or 3rd occurrence of a value in a delimited string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
==========================================================
|  Name_Level_Class_Section   |   Phone Num              |
==========================================================
|  Jacky_1_B2_23              |  1122554455              |
|  Johnhy_1_B2_24             |  1122554455              |
|  Peter_2_A5_3               |  1122554455              |
==========================================================
```

I am thinking of simplified my SQL statement as follows:

```
select 
    *, 
    substring(Name_Level_Class_Section, 
              CHARINDEX('_',Name_Level_Class_Section,
              (CHARINDEX('_', Name_Level_Class_Section) + 1)) + 1, 
      CHARINDEX('_',Name_Level_Class_Section,
     (CHARINDEX('_',Name_Level_Class_Section,
     (CHARINDEX('_',Name_Level_Class_Section)+1))+1))-    
      CHARINDEX('_',Name_Level_Class_Section,
     (CHARINDEX('_',Name_Level_Class_Section)+1))) as CLA 
from 
    Bookings 
order by 
    CLA asc, Name_Level_Class_Section asc
```

So that when I perform the SQL, it will give me the following result:

```
==========================================================
|  Name_Level_Class_Section   |  Phone Num     |  CLA    |
==========================================================
|  Jacky_1_B2_23              |  1122554455    |  B2     |
|  Johnhy_1_B2_24             |  1122554455    |  B2     |
|  Peter_2_A5_3               |  1122554455    |  A5     |
==========================================================
```

Is there any way to simplify my SQL?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` and the third parameter of `charindex` to get the position of the underscores.

```
declare @T table
(
  Name_Level_Class_Section varchar(25)
)

insert into @T values
('Jacky_1_B2_23'),
('Johnhy_1_B2_24'),
('Peter_2_A5_3')

select substring(Name_Level_Class_Section, P2.Pos + 1, P3.Pos - P2.Pos - 1)
from @T
  cross apply (select (charindex('_', Name_Level_Class_Section))) as P1(Pos)
  cross apply (select (charindex('_', Name_Level_Class_Section, P1.Pos+1))) as P2(Pos)
  cross apply (select (charindex('_', Name_Level_Class_Section, P2.Pos+1))) as P3(Pos)
```

Result:

```
-------------------------
B2
B2
A5
```

**Update:** Using your table the query would look like this:

```
select *, 
       substring(Name_Level_Class_Section, P2.Pos + 1, P3.Pos - P2.Pos - 1) as CLA
from Bookings
  cross apply (select (charindex('_', Name_Level_Class_Section))) as P1(Pos)
  cross apply (select (charindex('_', Name_Level_Class_Section, P1.Pos+1))) as P2(Pos)
  cross apply (select (charindex('_', Name_Level_Class_Section, P2.Pos+1))) as P3(Pos)
order by CLA asc,
         Name_Level_Class_Section asc
```

**Update 2:**

If you know for sure that your value never contains a period `.` and that it is always a four part name you can use [parsename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

```
select *, 
       parsename(replace(Name_Level_Class_Section, '_', '.'), 2) as CLA
from Bookings
order by CLA asc,
         Name_Level_Class_Section asc
```

Answer (score 2):

PARSENAME was mentioned as a solution if the string did not contain a period. If it does use this modification to change the periods to something else, then parse the value, and then put the periods back

```
  Select REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE('Jacky_1_B2.00_23','.','~'), '_', '.'), 2),'~','.')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following UDF (inline function rather than scalar)

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.INSTR 
 (
 @str VARCHAR(8000),
 @Substr VARCHAR(1000),
 @start INT ,
 @Occurance INT
 )
 RETURNS TABLE 
 AS 
 RETURN

WITH Tally (n) AS
(
    SELECT TOP (LEN(@str)) ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
    FROM (VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) d(n)
)

, Find_N_STR as
(
   SELECT 
    CASE WHEN DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY @Substr ORDER BY (CHARINDEX(@Substr ,@STR ,N))) = @Occurance 
     THEN MAX(N-@start +1) OVER (PARTITION BY CHARINDEX(@Substr ,@STR ,N) ) 
     ELSE 0 
     END [Loc]
FROM Tally
WHERE CHARINDEX(@Substr ,@STR ,N) > 0 
)

SELECT Loc= MAX(Loc) 
FROM Find_N_STR
WHERE Loc > 0
```

How to use:

```
 declare @T table 
 (
 Name_Level_Class_Section varchar(25)
 )
 insert into @T values
  ('Jacky_1_B2_23'),
  ('Johnhy_1_B2_24'),
  ('Peter_2_A5_3')

  select t.Name_Level_Class_Section  , l.Loc
  from @t t
  cross apply  dbo.INSTR (t.Name_Level_Class_Section, '_',1,2) l
```