# SQL Split Address Line into Separate Columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, query, substring, string-splitting

Whats the best way to split a comma list column into different columns? I am looking for a simple algorithm, heard it is best to avoid scalar value functions, as they might be slow. Searching into many methods, substring, find, splitstring; we need to run this algorithm across millions of addresses, so looking for best, optimal answer with good coding practice.

```
create table dbo.AddressTest (AddressLine varchar(255))

insert into dbo.AddressTest (AddressLine) 
values ('123 Maple Street, Austin, Texas, 78653, 555-234-4589')

-- may not require substring, just looking for good way
select 
    substring  as AddressStreet   -- Expected: 123 Maple Street
    substring(...) as City,       -- Expected: Austin
    substring(...) as State,     -- Expected: Texas
    substring(...) as ZipCode     -- Expected: 78653
    substring(...) as PhoneNumber -- Expected: 555-234-4589
from dbo.AddressTest
```

looking into this method also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449492/using-t-sql-return-nth-delimited-element-from-a-string

Comment: [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016)

Comment: hmm, is there a way to get value element 2, 3, 4, 5, and place them into select? trying to figure that out, looking for anyway

Comment: This one could be used as inspiration (or a duplicate question?) https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42398/2103

Comment: There will always be exactly 5 elements (and 4 commas)? How can you be sure? (Hint: Address parsing is *really* hard.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) is probably best in SQL Server 2016. I've tested against 1 million rows and returns results in 12 seconds (fairly contrived test).

You can use the [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) operator to produce the columns from your rows following the split as there are a known number of elements.

Code to setup

```
CREATE TABLE #Table (ID INT IDENTITY, StreetAddress VARCHAR(MAX))

DECLARE @I INT = 1000000

WHILE (@I) > 0
BEGIN
       INSERT INTO #Table (StreetAddress) VALUES ('123 Fake St, BigCity, My State, 12345')
       SET @I = @I -1
END
```

Code to retrieve split address elements

```
SELECT ID,
       [1] AS Street,
       [2] AS City, 
       [3] AS State, 
       [4] AS Code
FROM 
(
       SELECT ID, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS Rn
       FROM #Table
       CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(StreetAddress, ', ', ','), ',')
) src
PIVOT
(
       MAX(Value) FOR Rn IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) pvt
```

You can probably improve performance by eliminating the REPLACE in STRING_SPLIT, but you'll then need to TRIM your columns to remove whitespace.